# Screen support in LigGDX(Ios and Android)

Tags: android, ios, libgdx

I am building my game for a resolution of 800x480.

I would like to know will the engine automatically scale the scene if it is on a smaller or larger device?

Also, how do you set a default width and height for the new Robovm projects?

I am using Box2D and not to sure how the screen supports work for the different devices such as iphone and the android.

P.S i know scaling isnt the best option but for my case it will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A piece of advice, if you are using box2d than with this approach you are going to face lot of problems with your physics behaviour as your values are to large for camera.For example Bodies will pass each other without colliding and other such stuff.

To solve this problem use camera value as

```
 camera.viewportHeight = scrh/40f;
 camera.viewportWidth = scrw/40f;

 camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2f,camera.viewportHeight/2f, 0f);
 camera.update();
```

` 
 and  while drawing any asset set its size to orignal size/40f
 so that world step calculations will be in terms of 20 ,12 and not 800,480 an dthus improving ur physics behaviour.

For non box2d screens Sandeep's solution will always work fine for u.

Answer (score 2):

yes the engine will scalee it but for that you have to set a view port

in your create method do this

```
float scrw = 800;
float scrh = 480;

camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.viewportHeight = scrh;
camera.viewportWidth = scrw;

camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth * .5f,camera.viewportHeight * .5f, 0f);
camera.update();`
```

Comment: So i do this in each screen??

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to do this in each screen...